# How do I combine multiple parent-child relationships with different lengths using T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, parent-child

**Summary**

In an Azure database (using SQL Server Management Studio 17, so T-SQL) I seek to concatenate multiple parent-child relationships of different lengths.

**Base Table**

My table is of this form:

```
ID   parent
1    2
2    NULL
3    2
4    3
5    NULL
```

Feel free to use this code to generate and fill it:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
ID int,
parent int
)

INSERT @t VALUES
( 1, 2 ),
( 2, NULL ),
( 3, 2 ),
( 4, 3 ),
( 5, NULL )
```

**Issue**

How do I receive a table with the path concatenation as shown in the following table?

```
ID   path      parentcount
1    2->1      1
2    2         0
3    2->3      1
4    2->3->4   2
5    5         0
```

**Detail**

The real table has many more rows and the longest path should contain ~15 IDs. So it would be ideal to find a solution that is dynamic in the aspect of parent count definition.
Also: I do not necessarily need the column 'parentcount', so feel free to skip that in answers.

```
select @@version:
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8
```

Comment: Take a look at recursive ctes. This is exactly what you need here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE for this:

```
with cte as (
      select id, parent, convert(varchar(max), concat(id, '')) as path, 0 as parentcount
      from @t t
      union all
      select cte.id, t.parent, convert(varchar(max), concat(t.id, '->', path)), parentcount + 1
      from cte join
           @t t
           on cte.parent = t.id
     )
select top (1) with ties *
from cte
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by parentcount desc);
```

Comment: `lev` => `parentcount`?

Comment: @GSerg . . . That shouldn't even be there.  It is something I use for debugging to prevent infinite recursion.

Comment: It kind of is used in `top (1) with ties *` `order by lev desc`.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly Gordon nailed it with a recursive CTE, but here is another option using the `HierarchyID` data type.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[parent] int)  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,2)
,(2,NULL)
,(3,2)
,(4,3)
,(5,NULL)

;with cteP as (
      Select ID
            ,Parent 
            ,HierID = convert(hierarchyid,concat('/',ID,'/'))
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  Parent is Null
      Union  All
      Select ID     = r.ID
            ,Parent = r.Parent 
            ,HierID = convert(hierarchyid,concat(p.HierID.ToString(),r.ID,'/'))
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.Parent  = p.ID
)
Select ID
      ,Parent
      ,[Path]      = HierID.GetDescendant ( null , null ).ToString()   
      ,ParentCount = HierID.GetLevel() - 1
 From cteP A
 Order By A.HierID
```

**Returns**

[image]